# MySQL query optimisation - existing query runs too slowly

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to optimise the following query, but its running really slowly for me:

```
SELECT `trans_email`.*
, `email_statuses`.`recipient`, `email_statuses`.`status_id`, `email_statuses`.`message`, `email_statuses`.`status_received_at`
, `trans`.`doc`
FROM `trans_email`
LEFT JOIN `email_statuses` ON `trans_email`.`id` = `email_statuses`.`trans_email_id`
LEFT JOIN `trans` ON `trans_email`.`trans_id` = `trans`.`id`
WHERE `trans_email`.`type_id` = 0 AND `trans`.`company_id` = 1 
ORDER BY `email_statuses`.`status_received_at` DESC
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0

25 rows in set (4.87 sec)
```

Here's the output from the `EXPLAIN`:

           `id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: trans_email
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: trans_id
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 769970
     filtered: 10.00
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: trans
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,fk_trans_company,co_del_drft_type,co_drft_del_utc
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: trans_email.trans_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 5.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: email_statuses
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: email_statuses_trans_email_id_foreign
          key: email_statuses_trans_email_id_foreign
      key_len: 4
          ref: trans_email.id
         rows: 2
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)`

As far as I can see, everything is correctly indexed. (Note that `trans_email.type_id` is actually a bool, and has therefore not been indexed.)

Comment: Try an `INNER JOIN` maybe : `INNER JOIN trans ON trans_email.trans_id = trans.id AND trans.company_id = 1` and remove this condition of the WHERE clause

Comment: @MickaelLeger Shouldn't really matter where the condition is (if it did, it'd be a big fail in the plan optimiser).

Comment: @Amadan I can't tell if you agree with me or not, your answer say the same thing that I said but when I read your comment I'm not sure?

Comment: @MickaelLeger I agree with LEFT JOIN being the problem. I disagree about moving WHERE to ON being a requirement (`FROM a, b WHERE a.x = b.y` is equivalent to both `FROM a JOIN b ON a.x = b.y` and to `FROM a JOIN b WHERE a.x = b.y`).

Comment: Well, if he wants `trans.company_id = 1` where do you put this condition? If you just do `INNER JOIN trans ON trans_email.trans_id = trans.id` he will still have the same number of row than before - NULL value + if he adds the `trans.company_id = 1` in the INNER JOIN condition he will only return the desired value no?

Comment: @MickaelLeger: As I said, if a DB engine did that, I would consider it an optimiser fail, given that WHERE and ON have exactly the same semantics in an inner join. In an outer join, it is as you say, because the result is different based on when the restriction is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use LEFT JOIN though you require a non-NULL field in the joined table in your WHERE.

`` `trans`.`company_id` = 1 `` cannot be true if the LEFT JOIN produces a NULL row for `trans`, so none of the extra rows produced by LEFT JOIN (compared to inner JOIN) would be admitted in the end result.

With a LEFT JOIN, you produce at least 769970 rows (i.e. at least one per row in `trans_email`), then you trim them down to 25. If you had an inner JOIN instead, you would immediately cut down to 50ish rows (assuming roughly equal distribution of the boolean column) just from your primary index, then cut down to 25 with your boolean condition.

EDIT: Changing the other LEFT JOIN (the `email_statuses` one) will actually change your results, unless you have full coverage in your `email_statuses` table, and it shouldn't really affect your runtime that much, once the other LEFT JOIN is gone, so feel free to leave that LEFT JOIN as is.

Thus - try this one (only one word slimmer):

```
SELECT `trans_email`.*
, `email_statuses`.`recipient`, `email_statuses`.`status_id`, `email_statuses`.`message`, `email_statuses`.`status_received_at`
, `trans`.`doc`
FROM `trans_email`
JOIN `email_statuses` ON `trans_email`.`id` = `email_statuses`.`trans_email_id`
LEFT JOIN `trans` ON `trans_email`.`trans_id` = `trans`.`id`
WHERE `trans_email`.`type_id` = 0 AND `trans`.`company_id` = 1 
ORDER BY `email_statuses`.`status_received_at` DESC
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```